# Comment plugin in PHP Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook

I am using the facebook comments plugin in one of my portals, but it does not work exactly as I want.

I have installed a faceboom app inside my facebook profile. When a user loged with facebook in the comments API makes a comment this comments is made by my app profile in his/her facebook wall or profile.

I would expect the comment will be in my own profile made by the user that has performed the comment. It is possible to do it in that way?

Here is some code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/<?php echo $fbLang; ?>/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="<?php echo 'http://www.mydomain.com.com/index.php/es/?option=com_content&view=article&id=' . $id ?>" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="true" data-action="recommend" data-mobile="true"></div>
```

Comment: Can you show us some code? What is the endpoint you are calling in the graph api?

Comment: I have included the code I have in my PHP template

Comment: No, that is not a functionality the comment plugin provides.

Comment: Are there any other method to perform a comment in my facebook profile using another fb profile?